# Laravel pagination for multiple @foreach in one view

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade

*This is blade:*

```
<div class="container">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Companies</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Devices</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Vehicles</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Drivers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                @foreach($items as $company)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{isset($company['company'])?$company['company']->name:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($company['device'])?$company['device']->type:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($company['vehicle'])?$company['vehicle']->type:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($company['driver'])?$company['driver']->name:''}}</td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

*This is controller:*

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $items = [];
    foreach (Companies::all() as $comp) $items[]['company']=$comp;
    foreach (Device::all() as $index => $dev){
        if($items[$index]) $items[$index]['device']=$dev;
        else $items[]['device']=$dev;
    }

    foreach (Vehicle::all() as $index => $veh){
        if($items[$index]) $items[$index]['vehicle']=$veh;
        else $items[]['vehicle']=$veh;
    }

    foreach (Driver::all() as $index => $dr){
        if($items[$index]) $items[$index]['driver']=$dr;
        else $items[]['driver']=$dr;
    }
    return view('/welcome', ['items'=>$items]);
}
```

I need to make pagination for this table in blade. But I don't know where to put command in this situation.
I  wrote in "return view...$items->paginate" but i got error there.
Any solution?

Comment: Please check, hope this blogs will help you https://codeshipguru.blogspot.com/2019/10/implement-pagination-in-laravel.html

Comment: From my limited experience in laravel you need to give paginate a parameter to function.

Comment: @UrsolSolutions Yes, I know it. But where, in "return" or in "DB::"?

Comment: $items is just an array, it doesn't have a paginate function. The object eloquent returns however does. So you can call it on an eloquent object, not the array you create yourself.

Comment: In parent controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collection from the array and call paginate on the collection:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3])->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have, go to your controller for the view, and, at the top, use:

```
 $locations = Locations::paginate(10);
```

Hope this answers something.

Comment: Seems like it's working. 
But I can't show pagination button in view.

Comment: @goran_bl sorry i answer so late, in your view under the table you can do  {{ $items->links() }}

Comment: I make it. Worked with {{$items->links()}}, and have to change ::all to ::paginate(). But with datatable option, I make it better.

Comment: @goran_bl Ok nice, and istead of using paginate(10) or something you can also do paginate(0) which has different properties, or if you want to paginate them all, do something like paginate(9999), and maybe add a search bar with that.

Comment: I know. But with datatables its look pretier, with search bar and pagination work without page refreshing